# Checking root permissions from Haskell

Tags: linux, haskell, root

My program requires elevated permissions and hence it crashes when run without these.

Is there a way of checking whether a Haskell program has been run as the root on Linux?

I.e., differentiating between

```
sudo ./myProgram
```

and

```
./myprogram
```

Comment: Don't. The user might have configured their machine using permissions, kernel capabilities or ACLs so that your program can run as a normal user without actually requiring to be root. I've never heard of something that can only be granted by modifying the effective id. So your approach is naive.

Comment: I wasn't aware of this, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `unix` package, `System.Posix.User`:

```
getRealUserID :: IO UserID
getEffectiveUserID :: IO UserID
```

When run under `sudo`, I think they should both report `0` (root).

When run as a setuid, only the second one should report `0` (if I remember correctly).

The man pages for `getuid / geteuid` should clarify, I hope.